# PowerShell string interpolation not working

Tags: powershell

I'm starting to learn powershell scripting and I'm getting stuck on a simple problem (surely due to my inexperience): string interpolation.

I'm trying to print a list of directories that I'm obtaining with the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet. I've read in tutorials that to output a property of an object inside a string you should use `"${$variable.property}"`, so I tried with this code:

```
foreach($pluginDir in Get-ChildItem -Path "./Plugins" -Directory){
    Write-Host "Found plugin directory ${$pluginDir.FullName}"
}
```

The `Get-ChildItem` command is working correctly (I've tried by printing `$pluginDir.FullName` directly without interpolating it inside the string), however the string interpolation is not. All I get in the output from the above code is:

```
Found plugin directory
Found plugin directory
Found plugin directory
...
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: To debug use following inside the foreach : $pluginDir | Format-Table  Format table is great for enumerating through objects and displaying all the properties.  The property FullName doesn't exist.  Format-Table will give all the property names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
Write-Host "Found plugin directory $($pluginDir.FullName)"
```

More on command substitution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.3#command-substitution

Comment: Thanks, it works, apparently the tutorial I was following was talking s**t 